# How to describe $\#\{0\leq x<n:\gcd(x,n) \text{ is prime}\}$ the primes in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The above set actually comes from the following:

In $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ an ideal is prime if it is generated by an element $x$ such that for the integer representative $x$ we have $\gcd(x,n)=p$. To see this, we just apply the fact $(x)=(\gcd(x,n))=(p)$ and the third isomorphism theorem gives $\mathbb{Z}/(n)/p\mathbb{Z}/(n)\cong \mathbb{Z}/(p)$.

For this reason

> I was wondering about the number of prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, that is, $\#\{0\leq x<n:\gcd(x,n) \text{ is prime}\}$. Does anyone know of a closed form for this?

Comment: Isn't this $\varphi(n/p)$? (Here $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function.)

Comment: @user26857 You're right for specific $p$. The only other thing is that $p$ varies in the factorization of $n$, so its $\sum_{p\in X} \phi(n/p)$ where $X$ is the set of primes in the factorization of $n$.

Comment: Your question didn't say clearly that you want a closed formula for $p$ running through the prime divisors of $n$. Maybe you want to do it now.

Comment: @user26857 I realized this. Anyways, that answers the question.

Comment: I don't think $\sum_{p\text{ prime},\ p\mid n}\varphi(n/p)$ can be considered a closed form.

Comment: @user26857 Eh, it gives me a way to compute the number for $n$ that I know the prime divsors of. It is good enough.

Comment: I see. However, I'm curious if that sum can be written in a closed form since there are some troubles when $p\mid n$ and $p^2\nmid n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\#\{0\leq x<n:\gcd(x,n)=p, \text{where $p$ is prime and $p\mid n$}\}=\varphi(n/p)$. (Here $\varphi$ denotes the Euler totient function.) Then 
$$\#\{0\leq x<n:\gcd(x,n)\text{ is prime}\}=\sum_{p\text{ prime},\ p\mid n}\varphi(n/p).$$